# Datagridview to report viewer using parameter VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, reportviewer

I try to copy all columns in my datagridview (DGView7) to my report viewer.

I used this code, but it didn't work

```
  Dim myAL As New ArrayList()
    Dim row As List(Of String)
    For i As Integer = 0 To Basicfor.DGView7.RowCount() - 1
        row = New List(Of String)
        For j As Integer = 0 To Basicfor.DGView7.ColumnCount() - 1
            row.Add(Basicfor.DGView7.Rows(i).Cells(j).ToString)
        Next j
        myAL.Add(row)
    Next i

    Dim Params(0) As ReportParameter

    Params(0) = New ReportParameter("Ref", CType(myAL.ToArray(GetType(String)), String()))

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

It shows an error. I tried to change to this code string() -> Single(), but single is not defined

```
Params(0) = New ReportParameter("Ref", CType(myAL.ToArray(GetType(String)), Single()))
```

Can anyone resolve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're calling

```
Params(0) = New ReportParameter("Ref", CType(myAL.ToArray(GetType(String)), String()))
```

And wanting to pass in an array of strings(). *That's my assumption at least*

However you're passing an array of list of strings.

Try

```
Dim myStrings = myAL.Cast(Of List(Of String)).SelectMany(Function(r) r).ToArray()
```